# How to write this in Powerpoint VBA? 'Set a video file on the slide to start automatically in slideshow mode.'

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am regularly working with MS PPT with lot of videos embedded on the file. I want to run a macro that set the video in my selected slide to play automatically on start.

```
Sub SetStartAutomatically()
    Dim mySld As Slide
    Dim myVid As Shape
    Dim sldX As Integer

    sldX = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
    Set mySld = ActivePresentation.Slides(sldX)
    Set myVid = mySld.Shapes(1)

    myVid.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings.PlayOnEntry = msoTrue
End Sub
```

I tried the code above but it's not working.

[Start was set on On Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgLe1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the last line:

```
mySld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect myVid, msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious
```

Comment: Thank you @John. But still it doesn't work. After I run my Sub routine the start is still set to "On Click".

Comment: Hi John I am so sorry. My fault. Now your answer works. Thank you so much.